# How do I retain the query string after login?

Tags: 7

I need the user,opening a certain page of my site (www.foo.com/page_to_visit), to login and then go to the requested page, so I set up an hook_menu for this specific page and a callback. In the callback I added this code which works

```
drupal_goto('user', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()))
```

but if the url contains query strings (www.foo.com/page_to_visit?id=12&od=12) they are removed. I mean that, after login, the user gets redirected to www.foo.com/page_to_visit instead of www.foo.com/page_to_visit?id=12&od=12. How do I avoid this behaviour?

UPDATE: Drupl_goto has something supporting this. Produced this code, following documentation

```
$args = array();
$params = $_GET;
$args[] = $params['q'];
unset($params['q'], $params['destination']);
if (count($params) > 1) {
  $pippo['query'] = $params;
  $args[] = $pippo;
}
drupal_goto('user', array('query'=>$args));

$args results in --->
Array
( [0] => page_to_visit
  [1] => Array
    ( [query] => Array
            ( [id] => 12 
              [od] => 12
            )
    )
)
```

The result is odd for the redirect looks like
    http://www.foo.com/user?0=page_to_visit&1[query][id]=12&1[query][od]=12

Comment: Have you tried out the LoginToboggan module? It might handle the passing of query string after login but I can't be sure. Half the problem is that the login destination is already being passed as a query string: https://www.drupal.org/node/1671118

Comment: Surely I'll try. The problem lies exactly there...

Answer (score 0):

I think, my suggestion is :-

1. alter login form
2. add a hidden field for destination URL.
3. add submit handler  like `$form['#submit'][] = 'destination_redirect_handler'`
4. use `drupal_goto('destination_redirect_url')` in this `destination_redirect_handler`

Answer (score -1):

Modify your call to drupal_goto() like this:

```
drupal_goto('user', array('query'=>drupal_http_build_query($args)));
```

[drupal_http_build_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7.x) builds a formatted query string from an array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `query` must be _An array of query key/value-pairs (without any URL-encoding) to append to the URL._ (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x). Converting to a string will break it

Comment: Modifying the core `drupal_goto()` method is poor advice. Drupal has interfaces for doing this without hacking core. [Never hack core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/site-building-best-practices/never-hack-core).

Comment: Hey @ChrisBurgess, just wanted to clarify that I meant to modify the call to drupal_goto() like the one mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that's much better advice [with your correction](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/259641/revisions) Supriya! Thanks for improving it.